# Cocoa: Can I render ms office files on the WebView on the osX

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, webview, ms-office

In iPhone programming , i can open ms office files (.doc, .docs, .ppt, .xls, ...) on the UIWebView on the iOS using the below codes

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];    
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request]; // webView -> UIWebView outlet
```

But, I tried it by using WebView on the OSX

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];    
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[[webView mainframe] loadRequest:request]; // webView -> WebView outlet
```

But on the WebView of the OSX application, the program won't

open any ms office files.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

answering my question.

I solved this issue differently from my question.

I used QuickLook framework.

so now I can display ms documents to the QuickLook Panel.